# What is an object tree - XML Parsing?

Tags: xml

I am reading a tutorial on XML parsing with Java - http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaXML/article.html

He says "In DOM your access the XML document over an object tree". I guess its some kind of Data Structure and searched google for 'object tree data structure' but did not find any such DS.

Is object tree the same as tree DS or is it not even a DS ?

Comment: I'd assume that he means it is a tree of objects, so nodes and leafs. This is indeed how an XML document is represented in a DOM.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen- Which tree ? I see three types R, B and M. See wiki link - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object tree is a tree data structure holding objects at the nodes. In the specific case being referred to here, the DOM (document object model) is a tree structure representing the XML that is being accessed. Each node in the DOM tree will correspond to an XML node.

Wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model

W3C: http://www.w3.org/DOM/

Comment: See latest edit for a starting point (Wikipedia + W3C links added)

Comment: what does this XML node contain ?

Comment: you can found a javascript based DOM implementation from here http://xmljs.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @ertan - java only for now.

Comment: @AppleGrinder each XML node contains some type of information being represented in the XML document. For a description of the node types: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-udom/section3.html